# Graphing/charting of CPU utilisation

Tags: monitoring

So nagios can be good at graphing particular resource utilisation or other metrics, but I'm looking for a tool that can output a chart or other graphical representation of how much CPU time/CPU utilisation /all/ services on a server are currently consuming. I think New Relic could probably achieve this to an extent, but I was wondering if there was a popular open source app used for this.

In case I am explaining this in a bad way, my actual problem is that I have a shared server with suexec enabled (ie. httpd cgi running under multiple user accounts). I'd like to know which users are using the most CPU during periods of the day.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Newrelic](http://newrelic.com).

It's a simple and quick solution, especially if you're trying to troubleshoot a single server and don't have an existing monitoring framework.

It will give you this information [for free](http://newrelic.com/pricing/details) (with 24-hour retention) and down to 1-minute granularity.

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Graphite! See [Dashboards for Graphite](http://dashboarddude.com/blog/2013/01/23/dashboards-for-graphite/).

Answer (score 0):

RRDtools does enable you to have a circular database (to prevent the database from storing too much data) AND to make nice graphics.

http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool-trac/wiki/SystemMonitorScripts